# LVM: on simple raid1 with two legs Cpy%Sync never reaches 100% and always stays at 99.99%

Tags: lvm, storage, software-raid, raid1, redundancy

On simple lvm raid1 with two legs Cpy%Sync never reaches 100% and always stays at 99.99%.

```
lvm> lvs -a -o name,raid_sync_action,sync_percent
  LV              SyncAction Cpy%Sync
  safe            idle       99,99   
  [safe_rimage_0]                    
  [safe_rimage_1]                    
  [safe_rmeta_0]                     
  [safe_rmeta_1]
```

How can I troubleshot and fix this?

It is preventing me from issue other commands, and probably doesn't handle failures properly. One of the failing commands is:

```
lvm> lvchange --writemostly /dev/sdd1:y vg/safe
  Unable to change writemostly on vg/safe while it is not in-sync.
```